# how to enable blur background with lib jitsi meet?

Tags: jitsi, lib-jitsi-meet

I want to enable blur background with lib jitsi meet, I saw [jitsi-meet/JitsiStreamBlurEffect.js at master · jitsi/jitsi-meet · GitHub](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/react/features/stream-effects/blur/JitsiStreamBlurEffect.js) ,but still don’t know how to enable blur background. I checked [JitsiTrack](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-ljm-api#jitsitrack) setEffect( effect ) ,what is the effect specific for blur background?
Forum related links: [Does lib jitsi meet support blur background](https://community.jitsi.org/t/does-lib-jitsi-meet-support-blur-background/94060)?

Answer (score 0):

```
nano /usr/share/jitsi-meet/interface-config.js
```

edit the toolbar and make sure, you have "videobackgroundblur" inside:

```
TOOLBAR_BUTTONS: [
    'microphone', 'camera', 'closedcaptions', 'desktop', 'embedmeeting', 'fullscreen',
    'fodeviceselection', 'hangup', 'profile', 'chat', 'recording',
    'livestreaming', 'etherpad', 'sharedvideo', 'settings', 'raisehand',
    'videoquality', 'filmstrip', 'invite', 'feedback', 'stats', 'shortcuts',
    'tileview', 'videobackgroundblur', 'download', 'help', 'mute-everyone', 'security'
],
```

You can also set it programmatically i.E. in Vue:

```
        return {
      interfaceConfigOverwrite: {
        TOOLBAR_BUTTONS: [
          "microphone",
          "chat",
          "etherpad",
          "fullscreen",
          "recording",
          "desktop",
          "camera",
          "hangup",
          "fodeviceselection",
          "settings",
          "raisehand",
          "videoquality",
          "mute-everyone",
          "videobackgroundblur"
        ],
      },
      
    };
```